# What is a squad leader?

Tags: battlefield-3

I see things about the squad leader come up during games and I have heard of it before. What changes when you are it?

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of things that differentiate a `Squad Leader` from a regular `Squad Member.`

Here are the differences:

- A `Squad Leader` is identified by a star marker next to his/her name.
- A `Squad Leader` has the ability to make a squad private or public to others.
- `Squad Leaders` are awarded points when marked objectives are either attacked or defended.
- On `Hardcore` mode, `Squad Members` can only spawn on the `Squad Leader.`

You can find out more on the [Battlefield Wiki](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Squad_leader#Squad_leader)

Comment: Just to add, squad leaders issue orders by targeting an objective and pressing the "spot" key. I've actually have had people argue with me in game that there is no such thing as in game orders.

Comment: @k1DBLITZ: What's interesting is that in BC2, any member of a squad could give orders in the way you describe. Although this sometimes resulted in squad members fighting over which objective to mark, I liked that system better. I very rarely see squad leaders in BF3 that actually mark objectives.